# XSLT for-each loop iterating through 2 elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm a complete novice with XSLT so apologies if solutions to other questions relating to loops would work for my problem but I've had no luck so far.

I have an XML file with multiple nodes such as the following:

```
<Roles>
    <Role>User</Role>
    <Purpose>General User</Purpose>
    <Role>Staff</Role>
    <Purpose>Company Staff</Purpose>
    <Role>Admin</Role>
    <Purpose>Administration</Purpose>
</Roles>
```

I need to loop through these nodes and print <Role> along with its matching <Purpose>. However, if I use a for-each loop it will iterate through the <Role>s fine but print the same <Purpose> for each (just the first Roles/Purpose element.

Is there any way I can sync them up so that, for example, when the for-each loop is on its second iteration it picks the second <Purpose> along with the second <Role> so it ends up something like this?

```
User - General User
Staff - Company Staff
Admin - Administration
```

I have been looking at using params such as the following but I get "element with-param is not allowed within that context" error when complining (probably my lack of XSLT understanding using it wrong).

```
<xsl:param name="i" select="1"/>
```

I have to keep the elements separate (i.e. I can't just do <Role>User - General User</Role> due to annoying formatting reasons but if anyone could think an alternative to loops which would work as well I would appreciate it.

Comment: What version of XSLT are you using?

Comment: Version 1.0 at the moment but may be able to use 2.0. I'm creating .docx files using PHP so not sure if there are restrictions as to which version I can use. Tried setting it as version 2.0 in case that solve the error with xsl:param but didnt unfortunately.

Comment: "*print <Role> along with its matching <Purpose>*" is pretty meaningless. Please add the expected output of the transformation (as code).

Comment: To use 2.0 it's not enough to just set version="2.0": you need to make sure you are running an XSLT processor that supports 2.0. If you're in PHP then the default processor doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `following-sibling`. Something like:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Role">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::Purpose[1]"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
```

---

<strike>Works only in XSLT 1.0 (see comment Daniel Haley).</strike>

Comment: Note that if the OP does switch to XSLT 2.0, `following-sibling::Purpose` is going to output more than intended (the value of every following-sibling Purpose).

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, following-sibling is what I was looking for. Hadn't come across that from my previous searching but is exactly what I needed

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the [`following-sibling::` axis](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#axes). You'll want to select the first following `Purpose` sibling.

There's already an answer using `xsl:for-each`, so here's one using `xsl:apply-templates`...

**XML Input**

```
<Roles>
    <Role>User</Role>
    <Purpose>General User</Purpose>
    <Role>Staff</Role>
    <Purpose>Company Staff</Purpose>
    <Role>Admin</Role>
    <Purpose>Administration</Purpose>
</Roles>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="Roles">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Role"/>      
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Role">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ' - ', following-sibling::Purpose[1])"/>      
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output** (not sure if this is the output you want because you didn't specify, but it shows the concept at least)

```
<Roles>
   <Role>User - General User</Role>
   <Role>Staff - Company Staff</Role>
   <Role>Admin - Administration</Role>
</Roles>
```